# Estrutura de repetição fantasma

Tags: python

```
maze = """\
##############
#            #
#            #
#   ##########
#   #       X#
#   ## ####  #
#   #     ####
#            #
##############
"""
EMPTY, BLOCK, STEP, END ,WALL=" ", "*", ".", "X", "#"
UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT = "˄", "˅", "<", ">"
north, south, east, west=0, 1, 2, 3
movem = {
    north: (lambda x,y:(x, y-1)),
    south: (lambda x,y:(x, y+1)),
    east : (lambda x,y:(x-1, y)),
    west : (lambda x,y:(x+1, y))
    }

def solve(maze, x, y, move):
    found = False
    if 0 <= x < len(maze[0]) and 0 <= y < len(maze):
        if maze[y][x] == EMPTY:
            maze[y][x] = BLOCK

            if (solve(maze, x+1, y, RIGHT) or solve(maze, x, y+1, DOWN) or
                solve(maze, x-1, y, LEFT) or solve(maze, x, y-1, UP)):
                maze[y][x] = move
                found = True

        elif maze[y][x] == END:
            found = True 

    return found


if __name__ == "__main__":

    maze = [[char for char in line] for line in maze.splitlines()]
    solve(maze, 1, 4, EMPTY)

    for line in maze:      
        print("".join(line))
```

Vi esse código na internet, em uma versão mais antiga, e resolvi melhorar ele um pouco, e esse foi o resultado(Isso me custou vários meses), agora, estou aplicando esse mesmo código em AStar(oque está quase me custando um ano), para encontrar o caminho mínimo, Mas ainda não entendi uma coisa, como a função solver() executa várias vezes?, pois não vejo nenhum estrutura de repetição. Seria o "trabalho em conjunto" da variável booleana **found** com a condição **if __name__ == "__main__"**?

site em que encontrei o antigo código: [https://wiki.python.org.br/ResolvedorLabirinto]

Comment: Recursividade. É chamado a função `solve` dentro dela mesma.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou pesquisar mais sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código faz uma busca força bruta no labirinto. Ele sempre tenta ir primeiro pra a direita; caso não seja possível ele tenta ir pra baixo, senão pra esquerda e, por fim, pra cima. (Note que isso é exatamente uma rotação em sentido horário)

Isto é uma força bruta porque ele vai caminhar cegamente pelo labirinto até encontrar o seu objetivo. Dependendo de onde o objetivo estiver, ele vai caminhar pelo labirinto inteiro antes de encontrá-lo. Basicamente ele vai testar todas as posições até achar o objetivo.

Você disse que não entende como a função `solve` é executada mais de uma vez. Leia cuidadosamente: Ela é chamada varias vezes dentro de si mesma, neste trecho aqui:

```
if (solve(maze, x+1, y, RIGHT) or solve(maze, x, y+1, DOWN) or
    solve(maze, x-1, y, LEFT) or solve(maze, x, y-1, UP)):
    maze[y][x] = move
    found = True
```

Veja que a função `solve` chamou ela mesma passando novos parâmetros. É dessa forma que ela faz pra se mover. Perceba que na primeira tentativa ela passa `x+1, y`, ou seja, ela se move para a coluna à direita (por isso eu disse que ela tenta ir primeiro pra a direita). Se essa chamada retornar `False` ela tenta de novo passando `x, y+1` (ou seja, pra baixo), se não der de novo ela tenta `x-1, y` (pra esquerda) e, se esse também não der, ela tenta por último na `x, y-1` (pra cima).

Chamar uma função dentro de si mesma é uma técnica conhecida como recursividade.

[https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ciência_da_computação)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

Para transformar esse código em um A-star você precisa criar uma função de heurística (geralmente é a distância absoluta entre a coordenada atual e o objetivo), daí você aplica a heurística para todas as coordenadas vizinhas e chama o `solve` primeiro para a coordenada que gerou o menor valor na heurística.